# Statistical error in Simulation with random initial seed

Tags: simulation, error

I have a simulation which takes a parameter $a$ as input and uses random initialized weights.

If I vary the seed for the random input but keep the paramter $a$ fixed, the simulation return changes.

The statistical error is simply calculated by the variance, right?

How can I calculate the uncertainty on the parameter $a$, should I vary both ($a$ and the random input) or only $a$?

Comment: It is good practice to use a known seed for any random pre-experiment planning (such as simulated power for given sample size. However, if you use enough iterations in your simulation, the margin of error due to simulation should be negligible.

Comment: For example, if you plan to use $n=150$ observations to reject $H_0: \mu = 100$ against alternative $\mu_a=105$ where $\sigma=15,$ at level 5% with power around 99%, then the following code in R, indicates that all should go well. `set.seed(1234); 
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(150, 105, 15), mu=100, alt="g")$p.val); mean(pv <= .05)` returns power $0.99177$ and additional code `2*sd(pv <= .05)/sqrt(10^5)` returns $0.0005713965$ showing that the margin of simulation error for the power value should be within $\pm 0.0006$ (at least two decimal places of accuracy).

Comment: If I run the code above once more, but start with `set.seed(2021)`, I get power $0.99187,$ not much different than before and within the estimated margin of error. // The general answer is to program the simulation with enough iterations that the seed doesn't make much difference. // So If you need more-detailed help, please explain exactly what you're simulating and say how much results change when you change the seed.